# Samsung note - Default browser(Internet) is taking default border radius in input

Tags: html, css

In Samsung note default browser (Internet) is taking border radius in **input**, but i want to **remove** this

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

I am trying following CSS

```
input {border-radius: none;}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: try border-radius:0px ;-webkit-border-radius:0px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

```
select {-webkit-appearance: none;-moz-border-radius: 0px;-webkit-border-radius: 0px;border-radius: 0px;}
```